# Передача массива в функцию C++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться что не так с этим кодом.

Недавно начал изучать С++, проходя курс на stepic, вроде бы разобрался немного с указателями, но там вот слизал код функции определения максимума и и главного метода, заполняющего массив через указатель. Так вот по какой-то причине не могу передать заполненный массив телу функции. Не ругается, но выдает неправильный результат, возвращает 1. Попробовал пользоваться отладчиком, в функцию даже не заходит, а на стеке вызовов, значение аргумента массива интерпретируется как адрес ячейки памяти. Объясните дилетанту что не так я сделал

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max_element(int* m, int size) {
    int max = *m;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(m[i] > max) {
            max = m[i];
            cout << "Current Max (in function): " << max << endl;
        }               
        return max;
    }
};

int main() {
    int m[10] = {};
    for(int* p = m; p <= m + 9; p++) {
        *p = (p - m) + 1;
        cout << "*p = " << *p << endl;
    }

    int max;
    max = max_element(m, 10);
    cout << "Max is: " << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я переформатировал код и теперь, надеюсь, ошибка сразу будет видна. **Подсказка:** у вас цикл внутри функции только один раз исполняется.

Comment: Если пишете на C++, старайтесь избегать сишных массивов, используйте вместо них `std::vector`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас опечатка в функции `max_element`

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(m[i] > max) {
        max = m[i];
        cout << "Current Max (in function): " << max << endl;
    }               
    return max;
}
```

Функция завершает свою работу в предложении

```
    return max;
```

в первой итерации цикла.

Правильно было бы написать

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(m[i] > max) {
        max = m[i];
        cout << "Current Max (in function): " << max << endl;
    }               
}
return max;
```

То есть вынести предложение с `return` за пределы цикла.

Имейте в виду, что в общем случае `size` может иметь значение 0, в результате чего функция будет иметь неопределенное поведение.

Поэтому лучше возвращать из функции не значение максимума, а указатель на значение максимума, как это делается в стандартном алгоритме `std::max_element`

Также это плохая идея - использовать магические числа 10 и 9. Лучше ввести какую-нибудь именованную константу. Например

```
const int N = 10;
int m[N];

for ( int* p = m; p != m + N; p++ ) {
    *p = (p - m) + 1;
    cout << "*p = " << *p << endl;
}

int max;
max = max_element(m, N);
```